# how i make two search bar in page which return a single result if two key is same entered by user using javascipt html from mongodb, like redBus

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, full-text-search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbVM0.png)[it is a image of redBus I have question how i make to 2 key in two search and it return only one objects means bus detail from my nodejs and mongodb api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXVrl.png)

Comment: I really suggest you to study this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask because currently, your "question" won't get any attention, let alone an answer. Besides, "How do I build.........." questions are off-topic because they're way too broad. If you have no idea how to build something, you are encouraged to search, research, experiment, try to write some code, and when you're stuck at a particular step, then we can try and help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.